# How to set selected value in dropdown through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jquery code to get data from database-

```
$.get('loadTaskDetails' + $taskId, {taskId: $taskId}, function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, data) {$('#ddl_Deliverables').find('option[value=data.tasks_deliverable_id]').attr('selected', true);    
                });
                }, 'json');
```

I have a a dropdown (ddl_Deliverables) which already contains many options. I want the option value to be set selected with the macthing value coming from database through $.get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't interpret the variable therein:

```
find('option[value=data.tasks_deliverable_id]')
```

That string value is a literal string.  It's specifically looking for a value called "data.tasks_deliverable_id".  To use the `data` variable, you need it to be outside the string:

```
find('option[value=' + data.tasks_deliverable_id + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('loadTaskDetails' + $taskId, {taskId: $taskId}, function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        $('#ddl_Deliverables option').removeAttr('selected');
        $('#ddl_Deliverables').find('option[value="' + data.tasks_deliverable_id + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');    
     });
}, 'json');
```